# Multipel condition at SQL Case

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have 3 tables to join with:

```
ALERT_CASE_HEADER
 - alert_key
ALERT_ITEM
- entity_key
-status_id
-entity_name='Active Alert'
STATUSES
-name
-id
```

Both alert tables use alert_key and entity_key to link. The summation of case only take place if both keys are same value and `entity_name='Active Alert'` for each of the available status name. And the id column in table STATUSES is linked to ALERT_ITEM.status_id

Can I do something like this? I tried to run the script but it seem very slow.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN s.name = 'Pending' 
      AND ach.alert_key = ai.entity_key 
      AND ai.entity_name = 'Active Alert' 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS PENDING, SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN s.name = 'new' 
      AND ach.alert_key = ai.entity_key 
      AND ai.entity_name = 'Active Alert' 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS NEW, SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN s.name = 'cancel' 
      AND ach.alert_key = ai.entity_key 
      AND ai.entity_name = 'Active Alert' 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS CANCEL 
FROM
  STATUSES s, ALERT_CASE_HEADER ach, ALERT_ITEM ai;
```

(From an answer by the asker Nov 14 '17 at 9:53 that should have been an edit:)

The script i am using as per below, just focus on the 2 join statements.The second join is working but not the first one.

```
 SELECT CUS.ORGUNIT_CODE AS ORGANIZATION_UNITS,
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN S.name = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
    ) AS PENDING_AUTOCLOSURE, 
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN S.name = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
    ) AS NEW, 
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN S.name = 'Under Investigation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS UNDER_INVESTIGATION,
  SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN S.Name = 'Escalated' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS ESCALATED,
   SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN S.Name = 'Recommend True Positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS RECOMMEND_TRUE_POSITIVE,
   SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN S.Name = 'Reopen Under Investigation' THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS REOPEN_UNDER_INVESTIGATION
FROM
  STATUSES S,CUSTOMERS CUS,ALERT_ITEM AI
  JOIN ALERT_ITEM AI ON S.ID = AI.STATUS_ID
  JOIN ALERT_CASE_HEADER ACH ON AI.ENTITY_KEY = ACH.ALERT_KEY
WHERE AI.ENTITY_NAME = 'Active Alert'
AND   AI.ORGUNIT_ID = CUS.ORGUNIT_ID
GROUP BY CUS.ORGUNIT_CODE;
```

Comment: I am sure you are not expecting `CROSS JOIN` What is the relation with the table `STATUSES` of other tables ?

Comment: there are relation between statuses table  and the others tables?

Comment: Yes, there has a id column in table STATUSES that link to ALERT_ITEM.status_id

Comment: To get better solution, please add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doing a left join with old style joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071664/doing-a-left-join-with-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking to your code  i suggest you of refactor your query this way

using the join between the table instead of condition in case

```
  SELECT 
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN s.name = 'Pending' 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END
    ) AS PENDING
    , SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN s.name = 'new' 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END
    ) AS NEW
   , SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN s.name = 'cancel' 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END
    ) AS CANCEL 
  FROM STATUSES s
  INNER JOIN ALERT_ITEM ai ON s.id = ai.status_id 
      AND  ai.entity_name = 'Active Alert' 
  INNER JOIN  ALERT_CASE_HEADER ach ON ach.alert_key = ai.entity_key
```

Update after the new OP code

don't mix implicit and explicit join

```
   SELECT CUS.ORGUNIT_CODE AS ORGANIZATION_UNITS,
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN S.name = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
      END
      ) AS PENDING_AUTOCLOSURE, 
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN S.name = 'New' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
      END
      ) AS NEW, 
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN S.name = 'Under Investigation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
      END
    ) AS UNDER_INVESTIGATION,
    SUM(
      CASE
         WHEN S.Name = 'Escalated' THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS ESCALATED,
     SUM(
      CASE
         WHEN S.Name = 'Recommend True Positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS RECOMMEND_TRUE_POSITIVE,
     SUM(
      CASE
         WHEN S.Name = 'Reopen Under Investigation' THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS REOPEN_UNDER_INVESTIGATION
  FROM
    STATUSES S
    JOIN ALERT_ITEM AI ON S.ID = AI.STATUS_ID
    JOIN ALERT_CASE_HEADER ACH ON AI.ENTITY_KEY = ACH.ALERT_KEY
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS CUS ON  AI.ORGUNIT_ID = CUS.ORGUNIT_ID
  WHERE AI.ENTITY_NAME = 'Active Alert'
  GROUP BY CUS.ORGUNIT_CODE;
```

Comment: i tried, it get s.id 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: you error message is not clear  .. show the exact error message and be sure you have an id column in statuses  table

Comment: Yes, it has, below is the full error message:
ORA-00904: "s"."id": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 34 Column: 32

Comment: The error message is clear  invalid column name or the column name is missing.  the "invalid identifier" most common happens when you are referencing an invalid alias in a select statement.  ... show all the code you are using ..  (Error at Line: 34 Column: 32  the s.id in mysq answer  is not in line 34)

Comment: i made a new post in this question to show the script I am using

Comment: there is a relation between  customers and one of the others table ?

Comment: yes, CUSTOMERS.ORGUNIT_ID and ALERT_ITEM.ORGUNIT_ID.thats fine

Comment: it's has no error..but no record return from the query in my DB..it seem not related to data issue as my DB has 3237 records with AI.ENTITY_NAME = 'Active Alert'

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working after some data issue sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

## S.ID 00904 Invalid Identifier

> ORA-00904:    string: invalid identifier
>
> Cause:    The column name entered
>   is either missing or invalid.
>
> Action:    Enter a valid column name. A
>   valid column name must begin with a letter, be less than or equal to
>   30 characters, and consist of only alphanumeric characters and the
>   special characters $, _, and #. If it contains other characters, then
>   it must be enclosed in double quotation marks. It may not be a
>   reserved word.

The problem exists in these lines.

```
FROM
  STATUSES S,CUSTOMERS CUS,ALERT_ITEM AI
  JOIN ALERT_ITEM AI ON S.ID = AI.STATUS_ID
  JOIN ALERT_CASE_HEADER ACH ON AI.ENTITY_KEY = ACH.ALERT_KEY
WHERE AI.ENTITY_NAME = 'Active Alert'
```

1. *second line*: the alias `S` is defined for table STATUSES
2. *third line*: the alias `S` is used again for column `S.ID` **that column is invalid** *It means the table STAUTUSES does not have a column called ID.*
3. *second line*: you have added 2 more tables, and again you are using commas for that. **This is bad, very, very, very, bad**. Never mix ANSI style joins with "comma syntax", mixing those styles is a recipe for nightmares.
4. *second & third lines*: you have repeated `ALERT_ITEM AI`

.

```
FROM
  STATUSES S

  ,CUSTOMERS CUS  /* change this to explicit join */

  JOIN ALERT_ITEM AI ON S.ID /* <<< wrong column name */   = AI.STATUS_ID
```

**STOP using commas between tables.** If you remember this you will have a much easier SQL life.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,  query changed to explicit join and without comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN s.name = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
    ) AS PENDING, 
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN s.name = 'new' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
    ) AS NEW, 
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN s.name = 'cancel' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END
  ) AS CANCEL 
FROM
  STATUSES s  
  join ALERT_ITEM ai on s.id=ai.status_id
  join ALERT_CASE_HEADER ach on ai.entity_key=ach.alert_key
where ai.entity_name = 'Active Alert'
```

Comment: i tried, it get  s.id 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: What is the datatype of `s.id` and `ai.status_id` ?

Comment: To get better solution, please add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: both are NUMBER(38)

Comment: I suspect you have problem in your data. Better you please add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Sample data:
ALERT_CASE_HEADER
- NUMBER(38)  alert_key = 276006

ALERT_ITEM
- VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) entity_key = 276006
-VARCHAR2(64 CHAR)  entity_name='Active Alert'
- NUMBER(38)   status_id=1094

STATUSES
-NUMBER(38) id=1094
-  VARCHAR2(64 CHAR) Name=New

You were right, it seem data type issue between ai.entity_key and ach.alert_key?

Comment: that isn't adequate "sample data" it is a mixture of DDL and snippets of data. PLEASE add **a few rows of data, for EACH table**, as a table of text. Do this IN YOUR QUESTION (use the edit and add this detail). Don't use comments or images for this.