# Doing a left join with old style joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, inner-join, database-migration

So I'm currently transcribing OracleSQL into a new PostgreSQL database. While I'm translating Oracle's `(+)` joins to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, this works very well.

Except when combined with old style joins. Take this OracleSQL for example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1,
    table2 alias1,
    table2 alias2,
    table2 alias3,
    table3,
    table4,
    table5,
    table6 table6alias
WHERE
    table1.id_table3 = alias1.id_table3
    AND table1.id_table4 = alias2.id_table4
    AND table1.id_table3 = table3.id_table3
    AND table1.id_table4 = table4.id_table4
    AND table1.id_table5 = table5.id_table5
    AND table1.table1_id_table3_sender = alias3.id_table3 (+)
    AND alias1.id_svw_uebertragungsweg = table6alias.id_svw
    AND table1.id_table3 != 0
    AND ( table1.id_usr = 0
          OR table1.id_usr IS NULL )
```

It works very well on Oracle's SQL Developer. So I tried transcribing it like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1,
    table2 alias1,
    table2 alias2,
    table3,
    table4,
    table5,
    table6 table6alias
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 alias3
ON table1.table1_id_table3_sender = alias3.id_table3
WHERE
    table1.id_table3 = alias1.id_table3
    AND table1.id_table4 = alias2.id_table4
    AND table1.id_table3 = table3.id_table3
    AND table1.id_table4 = table4.id_table4
    AND table1.id_table5 = table5.id_table5
    AND alias1.id_svw_uebertragungsweg = table6alias.id_svw
    AND table1.id_table3 != 0
    AND ( table1.id_usr = 0
          OR table1.id_usr IS NULL )
```

Giving me this error:

> ORA-00904: "table1"."table1_id_table3_sender": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error on line: 12 row: 8

I've already done *only* the JOIN, and then it works flawlessly. When adding just one single other JOIN, it gives me this error, that the row can't be found (invalid identifier).

I've already read on the internet that LEFT JOINs don't red more than the first table of the FROM statement. But in this case that would be enough (in my view) - also just adding one other table leads to the error.

So what is my approach to solve this translation to PostgreSQL? Do I have to rewrite ALL of the old style JOINs into newer style ones (which would be very tedious, as there are a ton of these SELECTs) or is there something I just don't get my eyes on?

Comment: Don't mix implicit joins and explicit joins

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Explicit JOIN's are evaluated before implicit, comma separated joins. This means your ON clause only has access to table6 and table2 columns.

Comment: Yes better to rewrite to use explicit JOINS; its would be worth the effort put into, when you can easily fix issues which would make maintenance easy

Comment: Just to be sure: There is really no way of mixing them? (I'm totally on your side with maintenance, so I'm going to rewrite them anyways. Good point!)

Comment: Answer of @Damien_The_Unbeliever answered my last question.

Comment: Comma does CROSS JOIN with lower precedence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i resolve ORA-00904: "CI"."CATALOG\_ITEM\_ID": invalid identifier Error at Line: 2 Column: 52](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600494/how-do-i-resolve-ora-00904-ci-catalog-item-id-invalid-identifier-error-at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is (not sure if it's standard but most database engines seem to follow it) explicit joins are processed *before* implicit joins. At the point at which you're doing your join, the only tables/aliases which are in scope are `table6alias` and `alias3`. But you're trying to reference `table1` in your `ON` clause for the join.

As you suspected, the solution is to use explicit joins throughout, which also gives you more control over the order in which joins happen.

(Or the quick fix would be to put the `LEFT JOIN` to `alias3` immediately after `table1`)

Comment: "explicit joins are processed *before* implicit joins" - oooh, I tested a bit and this is exactly what's happening. That helped me a lot understanding my SELECT, thanks!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbliever . . . The comma operator in a `FROM` has lower precedence than `JOIN` -- this is based on the standard.  So the "sides" of the comma are processed first, which is why the table alias is not recognized.

Answer (score 3):

Don’t mix explicit and implicit JOINs. Matter of fact, just don’t use implicit JOINs.

Here is the query you want :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN table2 alias1 ON table1.id_table3 = alias1.id_table3 
    INNER JOIN table2 alias2 ON table1.id_table4 = alias2.id_table4
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.id_table3 = table3.id_table3
    INNER JOIN table4 ON table1.id_table4 = table4.id_table4
    INNER JOIN table5 ON table1.id_table5 = table5.id_table5
    INNER JOIN table6 table6alias ON alias1.id_svw_uebertragungsweg = table6alias.id_svw
    LEFT JOIN table2 alias3 ON table1.table1_id_table3_sender = alias3.id_table3
WHERE
    table1.id_table3 != 0
    AND ( table1.id_usr = 0 OR table1.id_usr IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing incorrect join  it should be like this:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 table1 left outer join table2 alias3 on table1.table1_id_table3_sender = 
 alias3.id_table3,
 table2 alias1,
 table2 alias2,
 table3,
 table4,
 table5,
 table6 table6alias
WHERE
table1.id_table3 = alias1.id_table3
AND table1.id_table4 = alias2.id_table4
AND table1.id_table3 = table3.id_table3
AND table1.id_table4 = table4.id_table4
AND table1.id_table5 = table5.id_table5
AND alias1.id_svw_uebertragungsweg = table6alias.id_svw
AND table1.id_table3 != 0
AND ( table1.id_usr = 0
      OR table1.id_usr IS NULL )
```