# Oracle Error "invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" when join

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I am trying to execute following SQL statement on oracle 11g

```
select product.product_id, category.category_id, product.name, category.description
from product , category
inner JOIN category_prodcut ON category.category_id = category_prodcut.category_id
inner JOIN category_prodcut ON product.product_id = category_prodcut.product_id;
```

but I get the following error:

> ORA-00904: "PRODUCT"."PRODUCT_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 56 Column: 32

how to solve this? what is wrong?

the product_id is there because when I do :

```
select product_id from product;
```

everything work fine

Comment: (Obviously,) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Comma means cross join with lower precedence than keyword JOINs, the JOINs are done first, product isn't in scope there.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Doing a left join with old style joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071664/doing-a-left-join-with-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 2):

I can only imagine that you are trying to write this query:

```
select p.product_id, c.category_id, p.name, c.description
from category_product cp join
     product p
     on p.product_id = cp.product_id join
     category c
     on c.category_id = cp.category_id;
```

Comment: I get ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 6

Comment: Missing a join.

Comment: adding join before category c solved the problem according your suggested solution but would you please explain why my statement did not work? and why this instead work?

Comment: @mark080 : You're trying to combine the explicit `join` syntax with the old comma syntax in your query. You should learn to use the proper join syntax as in Gordon's answer and stick to it.